# Enabling certain template parameters based on user provided template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, tmp

Consider the following class template:

```cpp
template<class T, std::size_t S, SomeEnum = SomeEnum::NOT_DYNAMIC>
class Foo {
```

Where SomeEnum would be defined as

```cpp
class SomeEnum { NOT_DYNAMIC, DYNAMIC };
```

This class has a private `std::array`, but based on the value passed by the user to SomeEnum, I would like to instead use `std::vector`. For example, if the user passes `SomeEnum::DYNAMIC`, I would use `std::vector` instead of `std::array`. This would be implemented through `std::conditional_t` and `[[no_unique_address]]`.

I am wondering if there is a way to "remove" the non-type template parameter `S`, in case the user passed `SomeEnum::DYNAMIC`. This is to avoid having the user type a size, when it is unnecessary because the underlying contaier is `std::vector`. Meanwhile, I need to keep the `S` parameter in case the user does not pass anything to `SomeEnum`, because `std::array` requires the size too.

Is it possible with some trickery, and if not, how would I solve this?

Current thoughts:

- Using std::conditional_t as explained,
- Using inheritance, or using a specialization (not yet attempted or thought of)
- Polymorphism is NOT an option

Comment: Why not feed container type as a parameter of template? What are other requirement of this template? Please provide various examples of useage and what is expected to be generated by template.

Comment: Would you mind doing something like `Foo<T, 5>` for an array with size 5, but [`Foo<T, std::dynamic_extent>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/dynamic_extent) for a vector?

Comment: This class represents a Mathematical vector. I thought of that option, but I don't know how much sense it would make to have a mathematical vector implemented through, say, std::map.

Comment: The approach taken by the standard library in such and similar cases is to use the maximum of `std::size_t` to denote dynamic or invalid size/indices. (see e.g. `std::span`'s `std::dynamic_extent` or `std::string`'s `npos`) With C++20 you can also write your own class type to use for combined size and `SomeEnum`.

Comment: @Artyer That's exactly what I was looking for. I overlooked how the standard implemented std::span, and this seems a fair solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A similar situation in the standard library exists with `std::span<T, N>` or `std::span<T>`: Omitting the template parameter entirely defaults the size to [`std::dynamic_extent`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/dynamic_extent) (`(std::size_t) -1`), which you can use to have a `std::vector` instead of a `std::array`:

```cpp
template<class T, std::size_t S = std::dynamic_extent>
class Foo {
private:
    std::conditional_t<(S == std::dynamic_extent), std::vector<T>, std::array<T, S>> container;
};
```